# Java hibernate Detached criteria, count / having, query

Tags: java, hibernate, count

can someone help me out with a query ?

Here´s the deal:

I have two tables

1- Group of users

2- Users

One group has a lot of users, but the thing is, the table groups holds the number of users it has on table users. But it happens that sometimes this number is invalid, I want to find the casees where the number in the table group is less then the users in the table users.

The SQL query would be like that:

```
select
 id_group,
 count(user)
from
 user inner join user
having 
 count(user) < group.number_of_users
```

In hibernate I cant do that, so far I got into this

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Group.class);
dc.createAlias("userCollection", "uc");
dc.setProjection(Projections.count("uc.idUser"));
dc.add(Restrictions.lt("????????", "??????????");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what does this mean "user inner join user "? What is the association between user and group (defintion of the entities) ?

Comment: one to many - "One group has a lot of users"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do a `DetachedCriteria` that is the count?

Then you `dc.add(Restrictions.lt(detachedCriteria, "??????????");`